# Trying to loop through all the objects in my json to get all the amount_refunded in php

Tags: php, json, laravel, loops, error-handling

This is my json in postman:

```
     [
    [
        {
            "amount_refunded": 1,
            "base_amount_refunded": 1,
            "base_discount_amount": 0,
            "base_discount_invoiced": 0,
            "base_discount_refunded": 0,
            "base_discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
            "base_discount_tax_compensation_invoiced": 0,
            "base_discount_tax_compensation_refunded": 0,
            "base_original_price": 1,
            "base_price": 1,
            "base_price_incl_tax": 1,
            "base_row_invoiced": 1,
            "base_row_total": 1,
            "base_row_total_incl_tax": 1,
            "base_tax_amount": 0,
            "base_tax_invoiced": 0,
            "base_tax_refunded": 0,
            "created_at": "2021-10-04 13:02:36",
            "discount_amount": 0,
            "discount_invoiced": 0,
            "discount_percent": 0,
            "discount_refunded": 0,
            "free_shipping": 0,
            "discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
            "discount_tax_compensation_invoiced": 0,
            "discount_tax_compensation_refunded": 0,
            "is_qty_decimal": 0,
            "is_virtual": 0,
            "item_id": 166,
            "name": "Configurable Product 16 - option 21",
            "no_discount": 0,
            "order_id": 85,
            "original_price": 1,
            "price": 1,
            "price_incl_tax": 1,
            "product_id": 1234,
            "product_type": "simple",
            "qty_canceled": 0,
            "qty_invoiced": 1,
            "qty_ordered": 1,
            "qty_refunded": 1,
            "qty_shipped": 1,
            "quote_item_id": 164,
            "row_invoiced": 1,
            "row_total": 1,
            "row_total_incl_tax": 1,
            "row_weight": 1,
            "sku": "Configurable Product 16 - option 21",
            "store_id": 1,
            "tax_amount": 0,
            "tax_invoiced": 0,
            "tax_percent": 0,
            "tax_refunded": 0,
            "updated_at": "2021-10-15 09:28:44",
            "weee_tax_applied": "[]",
            "weight": 1
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "amount_refunded": 80,
            "applied_rule_ids": "1",
            "base_amount_refunded": 80,
            "base_discount_amount": 8,
            "base_discount_invoiced": 8,
            "base_discount_refunded": 8,
            "base_discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
            "base_discount_tax_compensation_invoiced": 0,
            "base_discount_tax_compensation_refunded": 0,
            "base_original_price": 80,
            "base_price": 80,
            "base_price_incl_tax": 86.6,
            "base_row_invoiced": 80,
            "base_row_total": 72,
            "base_row_total_incl_tax": 77.94,
            "base_tax_amount": 5.94,
            "base_tax_invoiced": 5.94,
            "base_tax_refunded": 5.94,
            "created_at": "2021-10-15 11:23:54",
            "discount_amount": 8,
            "discount_invoiced": 8,
            "discount_percent": 10,
            "discount_refunded": 8,
            "free_shipping": 0,
            "discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
            "discount_tax_compensation_invoiced": 0,
            "discount_tax_compensation_refunded": 0,
            "is_qty_decimal": 0,
            "is_virtual": 0,
            "item_id": 169,
            "name": "Ski vest 92",
            "no_discount": 0,
            "order_id": 88,
            "original_price": 80,
            "price": 80,
            "price_incl_tax": 86.6,
            "product_id": 1267,
            "product_type": "simple",
            "qty_canceled": 0,
            "qty_invoiced": 1,
            "qty_ordered": 1,
            "qty_refunded": 1,
            "qty_shipped": 1,
            "quote_item_id": 171,
            "row_invoiced": 80,
            "row_total": 72,
            "row_total_incl_tax": 77.94,
            "row_weight": 5,
            "sku": "Ski vest 92",
            "store_id": 1,
            "tax_amount": 5.94,
            "tax_invoiced": 5.94,
            "tax_percent": 8.25,
            "tax_refunded": 5.94,
            "updated_at": "2021-10-15 11:25:07",
            "weee_tax_applied": "[]",
            "weight": 5
        },
        {
            "amount_refunded": 0,
            "applied_rule_ids": "1",
            "base_amount_refunded": 0,
            "base_discount_amount": 2,
            "base_discount_invoiced": 2,
            "base_discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
            "base_discount_tax_compensation_invoiced": 0,
            "base_original_price": 20,
            "base_price": 20,
            "base_price_incl_tax": 20,
            "base_row_invoiced": 20,
            "base_row_total": 18,
            "base_row_total_incl_tax": 18,
            "base_tax_amount": 0,
            "base_tax_invoiced": 0,
            "created_at": "2021-10-15 11:23:54",
            "discount_amount": 2,
            "discount_invoiced": 2,
            "discount_percent": 10,
            "free_shipping": 0,
            "discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
            "discount_tax_compensation_invoiced": 0,
            "is_qty_decimal": 0,
            "is_virtual": 0,
            "item_id": 170,
            "name": "testcron",
            "no_discount": 0,
            "order_id": 88,
            "original_price": 20,
            "price": 20,
            "price_incl_tax": 20,
            "product_id": 1260,
            "product_type": "simple",
            "qty_canceled": 0,
            "qty_invoiced": 1,
            "qty_ordered": 1,
            "qty_refunded": 0,
            "qty_shipped": 1,
            "quote_item_id": 173,
            "row_invoiced": 20,
            "row_total": 18,
            "row_total_incl_tax": 18,
            "row_weight": 2,
            "sku": "testcron",
            "store_id": 1,
            "tax_amount": 0,
            "tax_invoiced": 0,
            "tax_percent": 0,
            "updated_at": "2021-10-15 11:24:39",
            "weee_tax_applied": "[]",
            "weight": 2
        },
        {
            "amount_refunded": 0,
            "applied_rule_ids": "1",
            "base_amount_refunded": 0,
            "base_discount_amount": 0.5,
            "base_discount_invoiced": 0.5,
            "base_discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
            "base_discount_tax_compensation_invoiced": 0,
            "base_original_price": 5,
            "base_price": 5,
            "base_price_incl_tax": 5.41,
            "base_row_invoiced": 5,
            "base_row_total": 4.5,
            "base_row_total_incl_tax": 4.87,
            "base_tax_amount": 0.37,
            "base_tax_invoiced": 0.37,
            "created_at": "2021-10-15 11:23:54",
            "discount_amount": 0.5,
            "discount_invoiced": 0.5,
            "discount_percent": 10,
            "free_shipping": 0,
            "discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
            "discount_tax_compensation_invoiced": 0,
            "is_qty_decimal": 0,
            "is_virtual": 0,
            "item_id": 171,
            "name": "time",
            "no_discount": 0,
            "order_id": 88,
            "original_price": 5,
            "price": 5,
            "price_incl_tax": 5.41,
            "product_id": 1261,
            "product_type": "simple",
            "qty_canceled": 0,
            "qty_invoiced": 1,
            "qty_ordered": 1,
            "qty_refunded": 0,
            "qty_shipped": 1,
            "quote_item_id": 174,
            "row_invoiced": 5,
            "row_total": 4.5,
            "row_total_incl_tax": 4.87,
            "row_weight": 2,
            "sku": "time",
            "store_id": 1,
            "tax_amount": 0.37,
            "tax_invoiced": 0.37,
            "tax_percent": 8.25,
            "updated_at": "2021-10-15 11:24:39",
            "weee_tax_applied": "[]",
            "weight": 2
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "amount_refunded": 80,
            "base_amount_refunded": 80,
            "base_discount_amount": 0,
            "base_discount_invoiced": 0,
            "base_discount_refunded": 0,
            "base_discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
            "base_discount_tax_compensation_invoiced": 0,
            "base_discount_tax_compensation_refunded": 0,
            "base_original_price": 80,
            "base_price": 80,
            "base_price_incl_tax": 80,
            "base_row_invoiced": 80,
            "base_row_total": 80,
            "base_row_total_incl_tax": 80,
            "base_tax_amount": 0,
            "base_tax_invoiced": 0,
            "base_tax_refunded": 0,
            "created_at": "2021-10-19 08:49:35",
            "discount_amount": 0,
            "discount_invoiced": 0,
            "discount_percent": 0,
            "discount_refunded": 0,
            "free_shipping": 0,
            "discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
            "discount_tax_compensation_invoiced": 0,
            "discount_tax_compensation_refunded": 0,
            "is_qty_decimal": 0,
            "is_virtual": 0,
            "item_id": 172,
            "name": "Ski vest 92",
            "no_discount": 0,
            "order_id": 89,
            "original_price": 80,
            "price": 80,
            "price_incl_tax": 80,
            "product_id": 1267,
            "product_type": "simple",
            "qty_canceled": 0,
            "qty_invoiced": 1,
            "qty_ordered": 1,
            "qty_refunded": 1,
            "qty_shipped": 1,
            "quote_item_id": 175,
            "row_invoiced": 80,
            "row_total": 80,
            "row_total_incl_tax": 80,
            "row_weight": 5,
            "sku": "Ski vest 92",
            "store_id": 1,
            "tax_amount": 0,
            "tax_invoiced": 0,
            "tax_percent": 0,
            "tax_refunded": 0,
            "updated_at": "2021-10-19 09:06:19",
            "weee_tax_applied": "[]",
            "weight": 5
        },
        {
            "amount_refunded": 5,
            "base_amount_refunded": 5,
            "base_discount_amount": 0,
            "base_discount_invoiced": 0,
            "base_discount_refunded": 0,
            "base_discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
            "base_discount_tax_compensation_invoiced": 0,
            "base_discount_tax_compensation_refunded": 0,
            "base_original_price": 5,
            "base_price": 5,
            "base_price_incl_tax": 5,
            "base_row_invoiced": 5,
            "base_row_total": 5,
            "base_row_total_incl_tax": 5,
            "base_tax_amount": 0,
            "base_tax_invoiced": 0,
            "base_tax_refunded": 0,
            "created_at": "2021-10-19 08:49:35",
            "discount_amount": 0,
            "discount_invoiced": 0,
            "discount_percent": 0,
            "discount_refunded": 0,
            "free_shipping": 0,
            "discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
            "discount_tax_compensation_invoiced": 0,
            "discount_tax_compensation_refunded": 0,
            "is_qty_decimal": 0,
            "is_virtual": 0,
            "item_id": 173,
            "name": "time",
            "no_discount": 0,
            "order_id": 89,
            "original_price": 5,
            "price": 5,
            "price_incl_tax": 5,
            "product_id": 1261,
            "product_type": "simple",
            "qty_canceled": 0,
            "qty_invoiced": 1,
            "qty_ordered": 1,
            "qty_refunded": 1,
            "qty_shipped": 1,
            "quote_item_id": 177,
            "row_invoiced": 5,
            "row_total": 5,
            "row_total_incl_tax": 5,
            "row_weight": 2,
            "sku": "time",
            "store_id": 1,
            "tax_amount": 0,
            "tax_invoiced": 0,
            "tax_percent": 0,
            "tax_refunded": 0,
            "updated_at": "2021-10-19 09:06:19",
            "weee_tax_applied": "[]",
            "weight": 2
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "amount_refunded": 5,
            "base_amount_refunded": 5,
            "base_discount_amount": 0,
            "base_discount_invoiced": 0,
            "base_discount_refunded": 0,
            "base_discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
            "base_discount_tax_compensation_invoiced": 0,
            "base_discount_tax_compensation_refunded": 0,
            "base_original_price": 5,
            "base_price": 5,
            "base_price_incl_tax": 5.41,
            "base_row_invoiced": 5,
            "base_row_total": 5,
            "base_row_total_incl_tax": 5.41,
            "base_tax_amount": 0.41,
            "base_tax_invoiced": 0.41,
            "base_tax_refunded": 0.41,
            "created_at": "2021-10-19 10:27:53",
            "discount_amount": 0,
            "discount_invoiced": 0,
            "discount_percent": 0,
            "discount_refunded": 0,
            "free_shipping": 0,
            "discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
            "discount_tax_compensation_invoiced": 0,
            "discount_tax_compensation_refunded": 0,
            "is_qty_decimal": 0,
            "is_virtual": 0,
            "item_id": 176,
            "name": "Configurable Product 16",
            "no_discount": 0,
            "order_id": 91,
            "original_price": 5,
            "price": 5,
            "price_incl_tax": 5.41,
            "product_id": 1253,
            "product_type": "configurable",
            "qty_canceled": 0,
            "qty_invoiced": 1,
            "qty_ordered": 1,
            "qty_refunded": 1,
            "qty_shipped": 1,
            "quote_item_id": 180,
            "row_invoiced": 5,
            "row_total": 5,
            "row_total_incl_tax": 5.41,
            "row_weight": 1,
            "sku": "Configurable Product 16 - option 9",
            "store_id": 1,
            "tax_amount": 0.41,
            "tax_invoiced": 0.41,
            "tax_percent": 8.25,
            "tax_refunded": 0.41,
            "updated_at": "2021-10-19 10:50:02",
            "weee_tax_applied": "[]",
            "weight": 1,
            "product_option": {
                "extension_attributes": {
                    "configurable_item_options": [
                        {
                            "option_id": "212",
                            "option_value": 478
                        },
                        {
                            "option_id": "213",
                            "option_value": 480
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "amount_refunded": 0,
            "base_amount_refunded": 0,
            "base_discount_amount": 0,
            "base_discount_invoiced": 0,
            "base_discount_refunded": 0,
            "base_discount_tax_compensation_invoiced": 0,
            "base_discount_tax_compensation_refunded": 0,
            "base_price": 0,
            "base_row_invoiced": 0,
            "base_row_total": 0,
            "base_tax_amount": 0,
            "base_tax_invoiced": 0,
            "base_tax_refunded": 0,
            "created_at": "2021-10-19 10:27:53",
            "discount_amount": 0,
            "discount_invoiced": 0,
            "discount_percent": 0,
            "discount_refunded": 0,
            "free_shipping": 0,
            "discount_tax_compensation_invoiced": 0,
            "discount_tax_compensation_refunded": 0,
            "is_qty_decimal": 0,
            "is_virtual": 0,
            "item_id": 177,
            "name": "Configurable Product 16 - option 9",
            "no_discount": 0,
            "order_id": 91,
            "original_price": 0,
            "parent_item_id": 176,
            "price": 0,
            "product_id": 1222,
            "product_type": "simple",
            "qty_canceled": 0,
            "qty_invoiced": 1,
            "qty_ordered": 1,
            "qty_refunded": 1,
            "qty_shipped": 0,
            "quote_item_id": 181,
            "row_invoiced": 0,
            "row_total": 0,
            "row_weight": 0,
            "sku": "Configurable Product 16 - option 9",
            "store_id": 1,
            "tax_amount": 0,
            "tax_invoiced": 0,
            "tax_percent": 0,
            "tax_refunded": 0,
            "updated_at": "2021-10-19 10:50:02",
            "weight": 1,
            "parent_item": {
                "amount_refunded": 5,
                "base_amount_refunded": 5,
                "base_discount_amount": 0,
                "base_discount_invoiced": 0,
                "base_discount_refunded": 0,
                "base_discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
                "base_discount_tax_compensation_invoiced": 0,
                "base_discount_tax_compensation_refunded": 0,
                "base_original_price": 5,
                "base_price": 5,
                "base_price_incl_tax": 5.41,
                "base_row_invoiced": 5,
                "base_row_total": 5,
                "base_row_total_incl_tax": 5.41,
                "base_tax_amount": 0.41,
                "base_tax_invoiced": 0.41,
                "base_tax_refunded": 0.41,
                "created_at": "2021-10-19 10:27:53",
                "discount_amount": 0,
                "discount_invoiced": 0,
                "discount_percent": 0,
                "discount_refunded": 0,
                "free_shipping": 0,
                "discount_tax_compensation_amount": 0,
                "discount_tax_compensation_invoiced": 0,
                "discount_tax_compensation_refunded": 0,
                "is_qty_decimal": 0,
                "is_virtual": 0,
                "item_id": 176,
                "name": "Configurable Product 16",
                "no_discount": 0,
                "order_id": 91,
                "original_price": 5,
                "price": 5,
                "price_incl_tax": 5.41,
                "product_id": 1253,
                "product_type": "configurable",
                "qty_canceled": 0,
                "qty_invoiced": 1,
                "qty_ordered": 1,
                "qty_refunded": 1,
                "qty_shipped": 1,
                "quote_item_id": 180,
                "row_invoiced": 5,
                "row_total": 5,
                "row_total_incl_tax": 5.41,
                "row_weight": 1,
                "sku": "Configurable Product 16 - option 9",
                "store_id": 1,
                "tax_amount": 0.41,
                "tax_invoiced": 0.41,
                "tax_percent": 8.25,
                "tax_refunded": 0.41,
                "updated_at": "2021-10-19 10:50:02",
                "weee_tax_applied": "[]",
                "weight": 1,
                "product_option": {
                    "extension_attributes": {
                        "configurable_item_options": [
                            {
                                "option_id": "212",
                                "option_value": 478
                            },
                            {
                                "option_id": "213",
                                "option_value": 480
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            "row_total_incl_tax": 0,
            "base_row_total_incl_tax": 0
        }
    ]
]
```

I am trying to loop threough this json so I can get all the "amount_refunded values".
This  is the code that I have now but I don't understand how I can get the amount_refunded values.

Note that ->items is used and is correct because it needs to get all the items.

```
public function getRefundedOrders(Request $request)
{
    try{
        $response = Http::withToken($request->post('token'))
        ->get($request->post('URL').'/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=base_subtotal_refunded&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=gt');

    }
    catch(Throwaway $e){
        Log::error($e);
    }


    $refunds = json_decode($response);

    $user = Users::whereUrl($request->post('URL'))->firstOrFail();

    $refundedItems = [];


    foreach($refunds->items as $product){
        array_push($refundedItems, $product->items);
    }

    $refundedProducts = [];


    if (isset($response['message']))
    {
        return response()->json(['type' => 'error', 'message' => $response['message']]);
    }
    
    return $refundedItems;
   
}
```

I don't understand how I can loop through this so I can get all the amount_refunded from every object inside of this json.

Comment: Simple rule! `json_decode()`  the json string, then do a `print_r()` so you can see the structure. Once you see the structure you should be able to process it

Comment: P.S. As an aside, `if (isset($response['message'])) {` appears to no sense...if `$response` is a string (which surely it must be if you're passing it to json_decode()), then it will never have a "message" property. That's likely to cause another warning.

Comment: It really helps if you SHOW US THE REAL (COMPLETE) DATA to start with

Comment: And still that is **NOT Valid** JSON In fact its a real mess

Comment: edited the question with my whole code and json, it is correct now..

Comment: [Samples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) should be not only complete and representative but minimal. Extraneous parts can (and should) be removed, as long as the final sample demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the JSON you've shown is the contents of `$response`, there is no "items" mentioned anywhere in the JSON, so it's not clear why you included that or why you think it's working. It would definitely cause errors / warnings if you tried to use the code you've shown with that data.

Your JSON structure is an outer array, with multiple smaller arrays inside it - and each of those smaller arrays can have one or more entries.

This simple code will just output the value of each "amount_refunded" field, by looping through the outer array, and then looping through each of the inner ones:

```
$refunds = json_decode($response);

foreach($refunds as $refund) { 
  foreach ($refund as $item)
    echo $item->amount_refunded.PHP_EOL; //PHP_EOL just adds a newline character. Use <br/> instead for HTML output.
}
```

Working demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/728b81aa408b811b9d98a0c01d3dc782c4f05951

Comment: edited the question with my whole code and json

Comment: Ok so it looks like the structure was slightly more subtle than your original examples showed. I've updated the answer and the demo link, so it will work now with your updated data.

Comment: You really don't know what you want. So how we can help you!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your json is missing a closing "]", then decode it into an associative array using :

```
$string = '--yourjsongoeshere--';
$data = json_decode($string, true);
```

then set your total refunds to 0, loop through the arrays and add the total refunds to it.

```
$totalrefund = 0;
foreach($data as $datum) { 
    foreach($datum as $entry) { 
        $totalrefund += $entry['amount_refunded'];
    }
}
echo $totalrefund;
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer it solves the problem using core PHP

Comment: it says undefined index at:  $totalrefund += $entry['amount_refunded'];

Comment: Check the array that's produced by encoding the JSON and that it's valid. If that key (amount_refunded) is not going to be set for every entry, then add an if(isset...) to that line.

Comment: edited the question with my whole code and json

Answer (score 2):

You can use Laravel collection to get an array of `amount_refunded`.

```
$refunds = collect(json_decode($response))
    ->flatten()
    ->pluck('amount_refunded')
    ->toArray();
```

To get all data filtered by `amount_refunded > 0`

```
$refunds = collect(json_decode($response))->flatten()->filter(function ($item) {
    return $item->amount_refunded > 0;
})->toArray();
```

> Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#available-methods

Comment: It gives: 
[
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null
]

Comment: It works for data what you had there before. Now you changed that json.

Comment: because someone asked if I post the whole json where there is ["items"] in it.  it gave me the error null,null,null,null.null

Comment: That new `json` has not valid format, could you upload the correct format.

Comment: I edited my question and added the whole code that I use.

Comment: For that json format, my provided code is working.

Comment: The code that I send under the json. it is not working with that code...

Comment: Working demo: https://laravelplayground.com/#/snippets/8730c050-d075-4cad-8d31-360779ea1817

Comment: thanks it works  indeed ! I don't quite understand how I can make an if statement now, I need to check if a number is > 0 and then I have to add that whole json item to a list. I don't know how to do this here.. so to be more clear, I need to show all the items which have an amount_refunded that is more then 0.

Comment: I updated a post above, for that you can use `filter` method.

Comment: Thanks man.. I really appreciate this. been at this for a few days. Is there also a way I can remove the 0: and the 1: in the json?

Comment: What do you mean: `the 0: and the 1: in the json`?

Comment: nevermind, it works! thank you very much for your help! it is just the indexing. but it works correct.

Comment: Is it working or not... obviously you don't know, what you want.